Jmeter performance test : the different between simulating users via several cookies and Threads
I wanna do concurrent testing to simulate several users to search in the meantime.
As I knew, two ways to achieve:
1.setup cookie in Header and parameterize cookie.
2.setup Number of Threads with only one cookie.
By the way, cookie is for login Authority.
Please help me to explain what the different between this two way? And which way is to simulate real user searching?

JMeter comes with HTTP Cookie Manager which automatically extracts cookies from Set-Cookie response header and adds them to Cookie request header so if your test scenario assumes logging in - just add the HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan and that would be it.
More information: Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter
With regards to your question in general: each JMeter thread (virtual user) should represent a real user using a real browser so re-using one Cookie with multiple threads is not the best idea as each real user should have its own cookies.
